# groupby based on one column and get the sum values in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have a data frame such

```
mode    travel time 
transit_walk    284.0   
transit_walk    284.0   
pt              270.0   
transit_walk    346.0   
walk            455.0
```

I want to group by "mode" and get the sum of all travel time.
so  my desire result looks like:

```
mode           total travel time
transit_ walk   1200000000
pt               30000000
walk             88888888
```

I have written the code such as

```
df.groupby('mode')['travel time'].sum()
```

however, I have the result such as:

```
mode
pt              270.01488.01518.01788.01300.01589.01021.01684....
transit_walk    284.0284.0346.0142.0142.01882.0154.0154.0336.0...
walk            455.018.0281.0554.0256.0256.0244.0244.0244.045...
Name: travel time, dtype: object
```

which just put all the time side by side, and it didn't sum them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are strings in column `travel time`, so  try use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['travel time'] = df['travel time'].astype(float)
```

If failed bcause some not numeric value, use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['travel time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['travel time'], errors='coerce')
```

And last aggregate:

```
df1 = df.groupby('mode', as_index=False)['travel time'].sum()
```